# Receive 403 Forbidden error everytime I try to upload a file to s3 bucket. (PHP, SDK)

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sdk

I've already had two previous errors and here is the newest one everytime I try to upload a file to my s3 bucket:

```
PUT https://cactustestphp.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/videouploads/my-image.png` resulted in a `403 

Forbidden` response: AccessDeniedAccess Denied33D5F8 (truncated...) AccessDenied (client): 

Access Denied - AccessDeniedAccess
```

If anyone has any idea on why I'm having this problem, feel free to reply! I've posted my user and bucket policy below just in case there are any visible errors.

This is my php code:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Aws\S3\S3Client;

// Instantiate an Amazon S3 client.
$s3 = new S3Client([
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region'  => 'US-West', 
    'credentials' => [
        'key'    => 'garbage',
        'secret' => 'garbage'
    ]
]);


$bucketName = 'garbage';
$file_Path = __DIR__ . '/my-image.png';
$key = basename($file_Path);

// Upload a publicly accessible file. The file size and type are determined by the SDK.
try {
    $result = $s3->putObject([
        'Bucket' => $bucketName,
        'Key'    => 'videouploads/' . $key,
        'Body'   => fopen($file_Path, 'r'),
        'ACL'    => 'public-read',
    ]);
    echo $result->get('ObjectURL');
} catch (Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception $e) {
    echo "There was an error uploading the file.\n";
    echo $e->getMessage();
}


?>
```

My bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1488494182833",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1488493308547",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::056984788586:user/cactustest123"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:ListBucketVersions",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:Put*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::cactustestphp"
        }
    ]
}
```

My user policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check that your IAM user or role has the adequate permissions for that bucket, also take a look to the bucket policies to make sure that there are not policies like KMS SSE enforcing.

Comment: I updated my post to show my policies for my bucket and my user. You could  take a look at em.

Comment: Please put "s3:PutObjectAcl" in Actions

Comment: Adding this line to my user's policy still does not work.

Comment: Acyually, I just commented the line in my php code that was referring to acl and it worked!